# How to take user data for 2D array using strings and doubles in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have code for a 2D string array meant to hold 5 days of the week and 5 number values. Note this is in a Console Application of C#.

My only issue is it is kind of confusing to input the data on the user side because, as it stands, I must input all 10 data values in a row; there is nothing separating the days from the numbers.

I want there to be dialogue after the user inputs the first 5 days, telling them to now enter the numerical data.

Any different ways to do this?

Current code shown below.

```
  //Ask the user to enter five days of the week and rainfall data for each day
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
  Console.WriteLine("\n5. Please enter five days of the week.");

  //Store the data in a two dimensional string array named rainfallData[]
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      rainfallData[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
  Console.WriteLine("Doubles placed in myDoubles[] array.");
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("rainfallData({0},{1})={2}", i, j, rainfallData[i, j]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: *"I want there to be dialogue"* - You mean like a small pop-up window?  That would involve a UI technology, such as WinForms or WPF.  This looks like a Console Application, which would just be on the command console.

Comment: No not a window, just a line of text.

My plan is to preface the user input with something like,

"Please enter 5 days of the week"

and then preface the next half of user input with,

"Now please enter the rainfall of the given days."

The data needs to stay in one 2D array still, but because it is one array I am currently unable to split the two halves of data as mentioned.

You are right though, this is a console application! I went ahead and updated the info in the original post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a message after entering the first 5 messages, add an additional if statement and console output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
         rainfallData[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    if(i == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter rain data");
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked like a charm!!

I am a bit confused though... 

Why does the message display when i==0?

The first 5 values in the array are days of the week, which correspond with the array values of [0,0-4]. 

So why does the message pop up when it is time to enter data for the array values of [1,0-4]?

Comment: Thanks I could help! You partly explained your question yourself. After filling 5 values, the program checks whether it is the first set (at i == 0) or second set (at i == 1). Only after the first set the message will be displayed.